# Using meta database backend to combine active directory db and openldap local db

Tags: active-directory, openldap

I am trying to use the openldap meta back end to accomplish the following in a single query:

1. query the local openldap database for the account. (I control this resource and only a few accounts will be stored here.)
2. if the account is not found locally, then next query active directory (where I have no ability to create accounts)

The user will only be found in one or the other, but not both.

I have tried to follow numerous tutorials to accomplish this, but none have matched my exact scenario and I have been unable to tweak any of them into working order.

For testing I have created a simple LDIF backend to allow anonymous binds:

```
    database   ldif
    suffix     "ou=local,dc=proxy,dc=ldap"
    directory  "/var/lib/ldap/"
```

My meta is configured as follows:

```
    database             meta
    suffix               "dc=example,dc=com"

    uri                  "ldaps://ad.my.edu/ou=org-1,dc=example,dc=com"
    suffixmassage        "dc=org-1,dc=example,dc=com" "ou=axxxx,dc=sxxxx,dc=xxx,dc=xx,dc=xxx"
    idassert-authzFrom   "dn:*"
    idassert-bind        bindmethod=simple
                 binddn="cn=XXXX,ou=it,ou=services,ou=axxxx,dc=sxxxx,dc=nxx,dc=xx,dc=xxx"
                 credentials="XXXX"
                 mode=none

    overlay              rwm
    rwm-map              attribute uid sAMAccountName
    rwm-map              objectClass posixAccount person

    uri                  "ldap://127.0.0.1/ou=org-2,dc=example,dc=com"
    suffixmassage        "ou=org-2,dc=example,dc=com" "ou=local,dc=proxy,dc=ldap"
```

Here is the result of my search fromthe command line:

```
    ldapsearch -x -H 'ldap://127.0.0.1' -b dc=example,dc=com -s sub '(sAMAccountNAme=xxxxxx*)' -LLL

    slapd[1949]: conn=1014 op=2 UNBIND
    slapd[1949]: conn=1014 fd=9 closed
    slapd[1949]: conn=1015 fd=9 ACCEPT from IP=127.0.0.1:59624 (IP=127.0.0.1:389)
    slapd[1949]: conn=1015 op=0 BIND dn="" method=128
    slapd[1949]: conn=1015 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
    slapd[1949]: conn=1015 op=1 SRCH base="dc=example,dc=com" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(?sAMAccountName=xxxxxxxx*)"
    slapd[1949]: conn=1015 op=1 meta_search_dobind_init[0]: retrying URI="ldaps://ad.my.edu" DN="cn=xxxx,ou=it,ou=services,ou=axxxx,dc=sxxxx,dc=nxx,dc=xx,dc=xxx"
    slapd[1949]: conn=1002 op=9 SRCH base="ou=local,dc=proxy,dc=ldap" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(?sAMAccountName=xxxxxxx*)"
    slapd[1949]: conn=1002 op=9 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=32 nentries=0 text=
    slapd[1949]: conn=1015 op=1 meta_back_search[1] match="" err=32 (No such object) text="".
    slapd[1949]: conn=1015 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=32 nentries=0 text=
    ldapsearch[2054]: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
    slapd[1949]: conn=1015 op=2 UNBIND
    slapd[1949]: conn=1015 fd=9 closed
```

I have made some progress. I can now retrieve the user information from Active Directory if it is not found locally, but can't then rebind-as-user to finish authentication.

I receive a "Proxy operation retry failed" error:

```
    slapd[22555]: conn=1000 fd=8 ACCEPT from IP=127.0.0.1:35848 (IP=127.0.0.1:389)
    slapd[22555]: conn=1001 fd=9 ACCEPT from IP=127.0.0.1:35850 (IP=127.0.0.1:389)
    slapd[22555]: conn=1000 op=0 BIND dn="cn=xxxx,ou=local" method=128
    slapd[22555]: conn=1000 op=0 BIND dn="cn=xxxx,ou=local" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
    slapd[22555]: conn=1000 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
    slapd[22555]: conn=1000 op=1 SRCH base="dc=example,dc=com" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(uid=xxxxxx)"
    slapd[22555]: conn=1002 fd=11 ACCEPT from IP=127.0.0.1:35852 (IP=127.0.0.1:389)
    slapd[22555]: conn=1002 op=0 BIND dn="cn=xxxx,ou=local" method=128
    slapd[22555]: conn=1002 op=0 BIND dn="cn=xxxx,ou=local" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
    slapd[22555]: conn=1002 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
    slapd[22555]: conn=1003 fd=13 ACCEPT from IP=127.0.0.1:35854 (IP=127.0.0.1:389)
    slapd[22555]: conn=1003 op=0 BIND dn="cn=xxxx,ou=local" method=128
    slapd[22555]: conn=1003 op=0 BIND dn="cn=xxxx,ou=local" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
    slapd[22555]: conn=1003 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
    slapd[22555]: conn=1002 op=1 SRCH base="ou=xxxx,dc=sxxxx,dc=nxx,dc=xx,dc=xxx" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(uid=xxxxxx)"
    slapd[22555]: conn=1003 op=1 SRCH base="ou=local" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(uid=xxxxxx)"
    slapd[22555]: conn=1003 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=32 nentries=0 text=
    slapd[22555]: conn=1000 op=1 meta_back_search[1] match="" err=32 (No such object) text="".
    slapd[22555]: conn=1002 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
    slapd[22555]: conn=1000 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
    slapd[22555]: conn=1001 op=0 BIND dn="cn=xxxxxx,ou=xxxx,dc=a,dc=example,dc=com" method=128
    slapd[22555]: conn=1004 fd=16 ACCEPT from IP=127.0.0.1:35858 (IP=127.0.0.1:389)
    slapd[22555]: conn=1004 op=0 BIND dn="cn=xxxxxx,ou=General,ou=xxxx,dc=sxxxx,dc=nxx,dc=xx,dc=xxx" method=128
    slapd[22555]: conn=1004 op=0 ldap_back_retry: retrying URI="ldaps://active.directory" DN=""
    slapd[22555]: conn=1004 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=52 text=Proxy operation retry failed
    slapd[22555]: conn=1004 op=1 UNBIND
    slapd[22555]: conn=1001 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=52 text=
    slapd[22555]: conn=1004 fd=16 closed
```

Here is my revised meta configuration:

```
    database meta
    suffix dc=example,dc=com
    # The last rwm-map line maps all other attributes to nothing.
    overlay rwm
    rwm-map attribute uid sAMAccountname
    rwm-map attribute *
    #rwm-map objectclass posixGroup group
    #rwm-map objectclass posixAccount person
    #rwm-map objectclass memberUid member

    ##
    uri "ldap://127.0.0.1/dc=a,dc=example,dc=com"
    suffixmassage "dc=a,dc=example,dc=com" "ou=xxxx,dc=sxxxx,dc=nxx,dc=xx,dc=xxx"
    rebind-as-user true
    idassert-bind
      bindmethod=simple
      binddn="cn=XXXX,ou=local"
      credentials=XXXX
      mode=none
    idassert-authzFrom "dn.regex:.*"

    ##
    uri "ldap://127.0.0.1/dc=b,dc=example,dc=com"
    suffixmassage "dc=b,dc=example,dc=com" "ou=local"
    rebind-as-user true
    idassert-bind
      bindmethod=simple
      binddn="cn=XXXX,ou=local"
      credentials=XXXX
      mode=none
    idassert-authzFrom "dn.regex:.*"

    ##
    database ldap
    uri ldaps://active.directory
    suffix ou=xxxx,dc=sxxxx,dc=nxx,dc=xx,dc=xxx
    rebind-as-user true
    idassert-bind
      bindmethod=simple
      binddn="cn=XXXX,ou=xxxx,ou=sxxxx,ou=axxxx,dc=sxxxx,dc=nxx,dc=xx,dc=xxx"
      credentials=XXXX
      tls_reqcert=allow
      tls_cacert=/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx/fullchain.pem
      tls_cert=/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx/cert.pem
      tls_key=/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx/privkey.pem
      mode=none
    idassert-authzFrom "dn.regex:.*"
```

Comment: The base backend is the same on your "revised configuration"? Could you post your second "ldapsearch" command please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have searched for this solution for about a month and finally stumbled across the answer in the slapd man page after seeing an example config in a openldap thread in-directly related to my problem.

The key to my solution is the idassert-bind flags section for the ldap backend. I added

```
flags=override
```

From the slapd man page:

> Flags can be
>
> override,[non-]prescriptive,proxy-authz-[non-]critical
>
> When the override flag is used, identity assertion takes place even
> when the database is authorizing for the identity of the client, i.e.
> after binding with the provided identity, and thus authenticating it,
> the proxy performs the identity assertion using the configured dentity
> and authentication method.

Final working Backend LDAP configuration:

```
database meta
suffix dc=example,dc=com

##
uri "ldaps://127.0.0.1/dc=a,dc=example,dc=com"
suffixmassage "dc=a,dc=example,dc=com" "ou=local"
rebind-as-user yes
idassert-bind 
   bindmethod=simple 
   binddn="cn=admin,ou=local" 
   credentials=XXXXXXXX 
   starttls=yes 
   tls_reqcert=allow 
   tls_cacert=/etc/letsencrypt/live/my.site.com/fullchain.pem 
   tls_cert=/etc/letsencrypt/live/my.site.com/cert.pem 
   tls_key=/etc/letsencrypt/live/my.site.com/privkey.pem 
   mode=none
idassert-authzFrom "dn.regex:.*"

##
uri "ldaps://127.0.0.1/dc=b,dc=example,dc=com"
suffixmassage "dc=b,dc=example,dc=com" "ou=axxxx,dc=sxxxx,dc=nxx,dc=xx,dc=xxx"
rebind-as-user yes
idassert-bind 
   bindmethod=simple 
   binddn="cn=admin,ou=local" 
   credentials=XXXXXXXX 
   starttls=yes 
   tls_reqcert=allow 
   tls_cacert=/etc/letsencrypt/live/my.site.com/fullchain.pem 
   tls_cert=/etc/letsencrypt/live/my.site.com/cert.pem 
   tls_key=/etc/letsencrypt/live/my.site.com/privkey.pem mode=none
   mode=none
idassert-authzFrom "dn.regex:.*"

##
database ldap
uri ldaps://ldaps.my.site.com/
suffix "OU=AXXXX,DC=sxxxx,DC=nxx,DC=xx,DC=xxx"
rebind-as-user yes
chase-referrals yes
readonly yes
idassert-bind
   bindmethod=simple
   binddn="CN=IXXXX,OU=IX,OU=SXXXX,OU=AXXXX,DC=sxxxx,DC=nxx,DC=xx,DC=xxx"
   credentials=XXXXXXXX
   flags=override
   mode=none
idassert-authzFrom "dn.regex:.*"

# The last rwm-map line maps all other attributes to nothing.
overlay rwm
rwm-map attribute uid sAMAccountname
rwm-map attribute cn cn
rwm-map attribute sn sn
rwm-map attribute givenName givenName
rwm-map attribute employeeID employeeID
rwm-map attribute employeeNumber employeeNumber
rwm-map attribute uidNumber uidNumber
rwm-map attribute gidNumber gidNumber
rwm-map attribute mail mail
rwm-map attribute departmentNumber departmentNumber
rwm-map attribute department department
rwm-map attribute home extensionAttribute12
rwm-map attribute *
```

Comment: At the end the configuration was: `flags=prescriptive,proxy-authz-non-critical,override`? Did you put the `override` option in all the `idassert-bind` present in your config file?

Comment: It would be greatly appreciated if you could show your final configuration.

Comment: Thank you for adding your final configuration. It really helped me. One new question: How do you send the remote (database ldap) credentials to be validated?

Comment: In case anybody is in the same place as I am. What you have to do to authenticate is first search for the real `DN` of the user using suffix `dc=example,dc=com`. Then make the bind directly to that `DN`.

Answer (score 1):

To make the ssl proxy connection with any backend server either Active directory or other ldap directories, the openldap servers should be compiled with SSL/TLS.

To check your ldap server whether it is compiled with ssl/TLS or not run the below command

```
# ldd /usr/local/openldap/libexec/slapd | grep ssl
        libssl.so.10 => /lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f561c08d000)
```

It should return libssl then only it will make ssl connection with the backend ldap server. If your server is not giving the above output then compile the openldap package again and try.

For compilation first install the rpm - openldap-devel

```
# yum install openldap-devel  libtool-ltdl-devel gcc -y
```

then compile the openldap with below option - --with-tls=openssl

```
./configure --enable-bdb --enable-meta --enable-overlays --enable-ldap --prefix=/usr/local/openldap  --with-tls=openssl
```

I have used the below options to install the openldap-server from source code,

```
# export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/openldap/berkeleydb/include"
# export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/openldap/berkeleydb/lib -L/lib64 -Wl,-R,/usr/local/openldap/berkeleydb/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags"
# CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/openldap/berkeleydb/include/ -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include"
# export CFLAGS
#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/openldap/berkeleydb/lib:/lib64/"

# ../dist/configure --prefix=/usr/local/openldap/berkeleydb
# make 
# make install 

# ./configure --enable-bdb --enable-meta --enable-overlays --enable-ldap --prefix=/usr/local/openldap --with-tls=openssl 
# make depend 
# make 
# make install
```

Also add a line TLS_REQCERT never in file ldap.conf.

```
echo "TLS_REQCERT never" >> /usr/local/openldap/etc/openldap/ldap.conf
```

Then configure your slapd.conf file.