# Combining OpenLDAP and Active Directory via OpenLDAP meta backend

Tags: active-directory, authentication, openldap

We have an application that used to authenticate via our Atlassian Crowd instance, but after a major rewrite that authentication source is not available anymore. Now I need a solution to authenticate users from both our Active Directory and an OpenLDAP server, which was previously handled by Crowd.

The most promising option seems to be the OpenLDAP meta backend, and I now have a configuration where I can find users from both directories with `ldapsearch`, but authentication only works for AD users. I found a [couple of questions like this](https://serverfault.com/questions/883452/using-meta-database-backend-to-combine-active-directory-db-and-openldap-local-db), which were very helpful, but ultimatley didn't work for me.

```
           Application
               │
               ▼
         OpenLDAP (meta)
             │   │
             │   │
 OpenLDAP ◄──┘   └─►  Active Directory
```

This is my current configuration:

```
moduleload back_meta.la
moduleload back_ldap.la
moduleload rwm

include /etc/ldap/schema/core.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/cosine.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/nis.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/msuser.schema

database meta

suffix "dc=openldap,dc=Example,dc=com"
uri "ldap://openldap.example.com/dc=openldap,dc=Example,dc=com"
map objectclass user inetOrgPerson
map attribute sAMAccountName uid
#map attribute unicodePwd userPassword
map attribute objectGUID entryUUID
map objectclass group groupOfUniqueNames
map attribute member uniqueMember
protocol-version 3
#rebind-as-user yes
idassert-authzFrom "dn.regex:.*"

suffix "DC=ad,DC=Example,DC=com"
uri "ldap://dc01.ad.example.com/DC=ad,DC=Example,DC=com"
rebind-as-user yes
chase-referrals no
readonly yes
protocol-version 3
idassert-bind
  bindmethod=simple
  binddn="CN=username,OU=Service-Accounts,DC=ad,DC=Example,DC=com"
  credentials="PASSWORD"
  flags=override
  mode=none
norefs yes
sizelimit 999
idassert-authzFrom "dn.regex:.*"

suffix "dc=Example,dc=com"
rootdn "cn=admin,dc=Example,dc=com"
rootpw PASSWORD
```

It seems that the only problem left is the password field. According to the MS documentation both `unicodePwd` and `userPassword` exist in AD, yet neither works for the OpenLDAP server (which uses `userPassword`). I was unable to find out how passwords are hashed in AD, the accounts stored in OpenLDAP are hashed with MD5 or SSHA, depending on the age of the password I guess.

I tried `rebind-as-user` on and off for the OpenLDAP server, I tried binding with a username instead of anonymous, I have no ideas left.

What is missing to be able to authenticate against both directories?

Comment: The way I have seen this work in the past is to 'adopt" in of the directories as primary, and a synchronization process that periodically syncs the other directories with the primary.

Comment: Yeah, i thought about that. Problem here is that for the OpenLDAP server the mail address attribute was chosen for the login to prevent collisions with existing usernames in the AD. That makes synchronization somewhat difficult without changing logins for a couple of hundred users (not counting CI/CD configurations).

Comment: AD userPassword has a switch that enables it to be stored as plain text. I suspect it was for synchronization. I wouldn't use it though.This is an interesting field with interesting products. Microsoft has Identity Manager, but it probably is not that common compared to others like Ping/Sailpoint. If you only need password sync and login, that is probably the simplest scenario. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-identity-manager/reference/microsoft-identity-manager-2016-connector-genericldap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a working configuration. After realizing that the only thing not working was the authorization I moved the configuration from a separate LDAP server to the LDAP server that holds the accounts.

I added an additional meta database with a DN above the existing database and added the attribute `olcSubordinate: TRUE` to the existing database.

```
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module{0}
olcModulePath: /usr/lib/ldap
olcModuleLoad: {0}back_hdb.la
olcModuleLoad: {1}back_meta.la
olcModuleLoad: {2}back_ldap
olcModuleLoad: {3}rwm

dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: {1}hdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcSuffix: dc=hostname,dc=example,dc=com
structuralObjectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcSubordinate: TRUE

dn: olcDatabase={2}meta,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcMetaConfig
olcDatabase: {2}meta
olcSuffix: dc=example,dc=com
olcDbOnErr: continue
olcDbCancel: abandon
olcDbTFSupport: no
structuralObjectClass: olcMetaConfig

dn: olcMetaSub={0}ad,olcDatabase={2}meta,cn=config
objectClass: olcMetaTargetConfig
olcMetaSub: {0}ad
olcDbURI: ldaps://dc.example.com/DC=ad,DC=example,DC=
 com
olcDbIDAssertAuthzFrom: {0}dn.regex:.*
olcDbIDAssertBind: bindmethod=simple binddn="CN=user,OU=service user
 s,DC=ad,dc=example,dc=com" credentials="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 XXXXX" flags=override mode=none
olcDbMap: {0}objectclass inetOrgPerson user
olcDbMap: {1}attribute uid sAMAccountName
olcDbMap: {2}attribute entryUUID objectGUID
olcDbMap: {3}objectclass groupOfUniqueNames group
olcDbMap: {4}attribute uniqueMember member
olcDbChaseReferrals: FALSE
olcDbNoRefs: TRUE
olcDbProtocolVersion: 3
olcDbRebindAsUser: TRUE
structuralObjectClass: olcMetaTargetConfig
```

Now under `dc=example,dc=com` I get the OUs `ad` and `hostname`, with the latter holding the local accounts and the former showing the entries from AD, with the attributes I need mapped to their corresponding names in OpenLDAP.